# Github Deploy to Azure vNext Deployment Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

Why do I get this error:

> Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Cryptography.Internal
>   1.0.0-beta5 Adding NuGet package D:\local\UserProfile.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Cryptography.Internal\1.0.0-beta5\Microsoft.AspNet.Cryptography.Internal.1.0.0-beta5.nupkg
>   to D:\local\Temp\cd8689f0-09ed-466b-9b91-899e3296c1ba\approot\packages
>   System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path
>   'D:\home\site\repository\src\MyProject.MyLibrary.Model\bin\Debug\net451'.

Another:

> Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 4.0.0-beta5    at
>   System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String
>   originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption,
>   SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) Adding NuGet
>   package
>   D:\local\UserProfile.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor\4.0.0-beta5\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.4.0.0-beta5.nupkg
>   to D:\local\Temp\cd8689f0-09ed-466b-9b91-899e3296c1ba\approot\packages

This happens in the final stage when running the deployment command.

I have two class libraries and a dnx web project. It all runs fine on my local, I have `dnu restore` working and `dnx . web` working. So this leads me to believe it isn't an issue with my solution... but I could be wrong.

I'm running `1.0.0-beta5`